# How to subscribe to azure event grid with mosquitto_sub and certificate

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, client-certificates, azure-eventgrid, libmosquitto

I am working on Azure event grid (using it as an MQTT Broker) following this tutorial to generate the client certificates [Azure-event grid-generate-sample-client-certificate-and-thumbprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-portal#generate-sample-client-certificate-and-thumbprint)

On my machine it looks like:
[image]

And I know everything is correct because I  can publish/subscribe as described in the tutorial via  [MQTTX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-portal#publishsubscribe-using-mqttx-app)

But how in the world is it possible to pub/sub via mosquito?

I tried:

```
mosquitto_sub -h host.azure.net -p 8883 -t "topic/test/#" --username client-device1 --cafile /home/daniel/.step/certs/root_ca.crt

Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

The same error if I use the generated client-device1-auth-ID.pem

And it gets even more confusing if you want to use libmosquitto..
what do you set here:

```
mosquitto_username_pw_set(_mosq, kUserName.c_str(), ???);
//or here: 
mosquitto_tls_set(_mosq, cafile, capath, certfile, keyfile, callback);
```

So my question is how can I connect via mosquito(_sub/_pub) to my azure mqtt broker (which works via [MQTTX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-portal#publishsubscribe-using-mqttx-app) using the generated certificates from [Azure-event grid-generate-sample-client-certificate-and-thumbprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-portal#generate-sample-client-certificate-and-thumbprint))

Could the problem be related to the passphrase one has to enter during the certificate generation?

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of text, they are really hard to read, impossible for those that use screen readers and unsearchable. Post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using port 1883 for MQTT over TLS? The default port is 8883

Comment: I changed the hostname and the port, the original port is 8883

Comment: Then edit the question to show the correct port number as using the wrong port will give the error you have described.

Comment: We don't know with mosquitto_sub, but we have connected a Python based subscriber with event grid as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoS8shq8RWw&list=PLS47QG_BdOlRjQ5PuBw4ofsGu6fO5bRHI&index=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Steps to make it work

1.) Client authentication has to be "subject Matches Authentication Name"

2.) You have to set mosquitto_int_option(_mosq, MOSQ_OPT_TLS_USE_OS_CERTS, true);

(even if you do not have any os certs installed)

3.) mosquitto_tls_set(_mosq, nullptr, "L", pem.c_str(), key.c_str(), nullptr);